# Query running parent function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm new to JQuery. Is there a reason why LoadData() is executing even when it is defined no where else in the file? I'm a little confused here, I feel like this code alone shouldn't be doing anything.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function LoadData(){
    $.post("samefile.php", { exclusivity: "private" },
       function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });
}
</script>
```

Comment: How have you determined that the function is being called?

Comment: Open firebug, create a breakpoint and see who calls it

Comment: No obvious reason from the code you posted. More explanation or code required.

Comment: rename LoadData to LoadDataISDead and run the page. you will see a script error somewhere in the page.

Comment: @Shyju: I'm wondering that people do everything just not to use debugger :-)

Comment: I determined it was being called because it was alerting the data.
@Shyju saved the day though, thank you.

Comment: @zerkms, I didnt even know firebug existed, but im installing as I type; thanks

Comment: @Rick Ryan: firebug or just F12 if you use chrome

Comment: @RickRyan you took the red pill dude - welcome to the real world

Answer (score 0):

**Shyju's Comment:**

"Rename LoadData to LoadDataISDead and run the page. you will see a script error somewhere in the page."